# Replace certain content from repeated content inside HTML tag with an ID using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm working on code that replaces strings in "index.html" file and there is a repeated string inside HTML tags l.
I'm using PHP to replace string with another one

***The problem is***  that string may be repeated in many tags so how to make PHP code change string inside tags with certain id, because this PHP code replace all strings inside file

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("p").click(function () {
        var mid= this.id;
        var yyy = document.getElementById(mid).innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("oldvalue").value = yyy;
        document.getElementById("iddddd").value=mid;
         document.getElementById("newvalue").value ="text2"
    });
});
```

```html
<p id="parg1" >text1 </p>
<p id="parg2">text1 </p>
<form action="changeText.php" method="POST" >
  <input type="hidden" id="oldvalue" name="oldvalue" class="inputText">
  <input type="hidden" id="newvalue" name="newvalue"  class="inputText" >
    <input type="hidden" id="iddddd" name="id"  class="inputText">

  <input type="submit" id="submitbutton" value="Save" >
</form>
```

//php code

```
$content=file_get_contents("index.html");
$content_chunks=explode($_POST['oldvalue'], $content);
$content=implode($_POST['newvalue'], $content_chunks);
file_put_contents("index.html", $content);
//result from that is
//<p id="parg1" >text2 </p>
//<p id="parg2">text2 </p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) for this you can read more about it at the php docs.

here's a simple example :

```
<?php 
function replaceByID(String $html,String $id,String $search,String $replace) : String 
{
$dom = new \DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));

$element = $dom->getElementByID($id);
$element->nodeValue = str_replace($search,$replace,$element->nodeValue);

$html = $dom->saveHTML();
return $html;
}



$file = 'index.html';
$html = file_get_contents($file);
$oldText = htmlspecialchars($_POST['oldValue']);
$newText = htmlspecialchars($_POST['newValue']);
$html = replaceByID($html,'parg1',$oldText,$newText);
```

**EDIT :**

I just tested this function and it works perfectly , i guess it can get the job done for you.

If you are working on a project where you need to manipulate or edit HTML files i highly recommend you learn about [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction) and [PHP DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) .

Comment: Big thanks for you @azjezz 
I will learn about them soon 
thanks again 
It worked 100% just added"file_put_contents($file, $html);
" at the end